# Constructors when creating a array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

When I'm creating an array of objects, how can I add the argument for the constructor inside each object? Like this:

```
foos = new Foo[10];
```

How do I make 10 objects with their constructors? I do not understand where do I put the arguments that is passed to the constructors of every object?

Comment: you just defined the array, now you need to loop over it and initialize each element as `foos[i] = new Foo(...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foos = new Foo[10];
```

creates an array that can hold references to 10 `Foo` instances. However, all the references are initialized to null.

You must call the constructor for each element of the array separately, at which point you can specify whatever argument you wish :

```
foos[0] = new Foo (...whatever arguments the constructor requires...);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just the allocation for a new array object of type Foo to hold multiple elements. In order to create and store actual object you will do something like this:

```
foos[0]=new Foo(); //Call constructor here
.
.
.
foos[10]= new Foo(); //Call constructor here
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foos = new Foo[10];
```

This is create an array type `Foo`, this is not creating object

for Initializing do following:

```
for(int i=0;i<foos.length; i++){
   foos[i] =  new Foo (your-argument);
}
```

See [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

You can do it inline like so:

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[] {
                  new Foo(1),
                  new Foo(2),
                  new Foo(10)
               };
```

Or like so:

```
Foo[] foos = {
                new Foo(1),
                new Foo(2),
                new Foo(10)
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say that Foo take a String as an argument so the constructor for Foo is something like this:

```
public Foo(String arg){
this.arg = arg;
}
```

if arguments you need to pass to the constructors are different from each other, so you will need to use separate initialization for every element. as @Sanjeev mentioned but with passing an argument.

```
foos[0]=new Foo(argOne);
.
.
foos[10]= new Foo(argTen);
```

on the other hand if your arguments are related to to an array index, you should use loop as @Sumit mentioned

```
for(int i=0;i<foos.length; i++){
   foos[i] =  new Foo (arg + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in order to create "10" new objects you need to create the array to hold the objects and then loop over the list while adding a new object to each index of the array.

```
int foosSize = 10;
Foo[] foos = new foos[foosSize];

for(int i = 0; i < foosSize; i++) {
    foos[i] = new Foo();
}
```

this will create a new foo object and add it to the index in the array you have created.